# How to Include Asset File in Homepage Of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have created a CSS File in Site Assets. I want to include that css file globally which will affect in all pages.

Ex: I have changed styles of menu. i want that changes to replicate in all pages. I'm very new to SharePoint, sorry if my questions are not making sense.

Help on this will be very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options depending on your environment. I know you said you are new to SharePoint, so if you need me to clarify more, please ask.

If you are talking about one particular site collection, then the easiest way is to just customize your master page. You can find out more about that here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-sharepoint-designer/

If you are talking about an entire SharePoint farm (as in every single site collection across the entire SharePoint instance), you can find more information here (I would specifically, in your case, go for the answer provided by Iman Abidi if all it is is a CSS file, as it doesn't involve any custom coding and only involves out of the box features): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75480/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-custom-css-javascript-sharepoint-2013-site

Let me know if that works for ya or if you need anything else!